# Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowBasePlugin']

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

Getting an error when running gradlew clean
Error is:

```
Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowBasePlugin']
   > No signature of method: org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader.allowPackage() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.apache.tools.zip]
```

I tried with Gradle 2 and 3

Comment: Mind to share your `build.gradle`?